# Need help to understand a density histogram

Tags: statistics

I've a density histogram, I don't understand. I hope somebody can help me with that.

The histogram: [image: http://www.filedropper.com/capture_5]

I know that a density histogram is the bar areas sum to 1. But I don't understand the histogram I have. It's a histogram of a consumption. Is it positive? How is the density? Is it symmetric or skewed?

Comment: it looks like a mixture of an exponential and a gamma (or something similar). Might be a useful way to model it.

Answer (score 0):

In an ordinary histogram the area of a bar is equal to the frequency. In this example the area of a bar is equal to the relative frequency = frequency divided by sum of frequencies.

So, for example, the very leftmost bar has height about 0.49 and width 0.5, so area = 0.245 - which means that about 24.5% of the observations are found to take a value of between 0 and 0.4 (whatever HE$Q is).

The distribution is not symmetrical. There is a tail stretching out on the right, so the distribution is positively skewed.

Comment: Isn't the width 0.5? How did you find the area?

Comment: Is it something you calculated?

Comment: Corrected the width now

Comment: But how did you find the area?

Comment: Area = width $\times$ height $=0.5 \times 0.49 =0.245$